# How do I get class file variable to another activity and access via button using intent not putExtra?

Tags: java, android, json

my problem is when I scan Qr code, I want to get the class file variables
and send via btnSearch button to an another activity. plz help me how to do it? sorry for poor English

**This is My class file**

```java
public class UploadDataGetter {

    @SerializedName("record_id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    private static String name;

    @SerializedName("full_address")
    private String address;

    @SerializedName("contact")
    private String contact;

    @SerializedName("dilivery_place")
    private String dplace;

    @SerializedName("dilivery_place")
    private String  fdetails;


    @SerializedName("no_of_normal")
    private int  noOfNormal;

    @SerializedName("no_of_classified")
    private int  noOfClassified;

    @SerializedName("no_of_cds")
    private int  noOfCds;



    public UploadDataGetter(
            //constuctor's para
                        int record_id,
                        String full_name,
                        String full_address,
                        String contact_number,
                        String dilivery_place ,
                        String further_details,
                        int no_of_normal,
                        int no_of_classified,
                        int no_of_cds

    )
    {
        id = record_id;
        name    = full_name;
        address = full_address;
        contact = contact_number;
        dplace  = dilivery_place;
        fdetails = further_details;

        noOfNormal = no_of_normal;
        noOfClassified= no_of_classified;
        noOfCds = no_of_cds;

        String  img_collector ;
        String  dilivery_status ;
        double  geo_long;
        double  geo_lat;

    }

    public
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public
    void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static
    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public
    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public
    String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public
    void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public
    String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public
    void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public
    String getDplace() {
        return dplace;
    }

    public
    void setDplace(String dplace) {
        this.dplace = dplace;
    }

    public
    String getFdetails() {
        return fdetails;
    }

    public
    void setFdetails(String fdetails) {
        this.fdetails = fdetails;
    }

    public
    int getNoOfNormal() {
        return noOfNormal;
    }

    public
    void setNoOfNormal(int noOfNormal) {
        this.noOfNormal = noOfNormal;
    }

    public
    int getNoOfClassified() {
        return noOfClassified;
    }

    public
    void setNoOfClassified(int noOfClassified) {
        this.noOfClassified = noOfClassified;
    }

    public
    int getNoOfCds() {
        return noOfCds;
    }

    public
    void setNoOfCds(int noOfCds) {
        this.noOfCds = noOfCds;
    }
```

**this is my Qr Activity,**

```java
public class QrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static UploadDataGetter id;
    public static UploadDataGetter name;
    public static UploadDataGetter address;
    public static UploadDataGetter dplace;
    public static UploadDataGetter fdetails;
    public static UploadDataGetter noOfNormal;
    public static UploadDataGetter noOfClassified;
    public static UploadDataGetter noOfCds;
    public static UploadDataGetter img_collector;
    public static UploadDataGetter dilivery_status;



    /**
     * QR code declaration
     */

    Button btnscan, btnSearch;
    TextView lblSearch;

    TextView ID;
    TextView DPlace;
    TextView Address;
    TextView name;
    TextView contact;
    private Object uploadDataGetter;
    private String result;


    @Override
    protected
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);

        btnscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscan);
        btnscan.setClickable(false);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setClickable(false);
        lblSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSearch);



        final Activity activity = this;
        btnscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public
            void onClick(View v) {
                btnscan.setClickable(true);
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();



            }


        });

        //call the class var
        if (this.getIntent().getAction().equals("moveData"))
            moveData();
    }

    private void moveData() {



        String id = uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String name = uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String address = uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String dplace = uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String noOfNormal= uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String noOfClassified = uploadDataGetter.toString();
        String noOfCds = uploadDataGetter.toString();




        //this is for Calling class file




    }





    @Override
    protected
    void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {

            if (result.getContents() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                /**
                 * Qr code result
                 * */
                lblSearch.setText(result.getContents());

                // Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }




         // "Go to Second Activity" button click
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public
            void onClick(View v) {
                btnSearch.setClickable(true);

                Intent myIntent= new Intent(QrActivity.this, DistributionDetails.class);


                myIntent.setAction("moveData");


                startActivity(myIntent);


            }

        };
        btnscan.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }


    public
    void getResults(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are seeing

Comment: how to get the variables from class file called UploadDataGetter and assign those values to these variable (id, name, address)?

Comment: where do you want to access

Comment: I want to access New activity's                                                               
  TextView ID      =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblID);
        DPlace  =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDPlace);
        Address=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAddress);
        name =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUname);
        contact  =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTelenum);

Comment: this does not make sense, are you trying to set values in new activity from the update Getter object passed to QActivity? via intent

Comment: yes That's I want

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your class with this

```
public class UploadDataGetter implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("record_id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("full_address")
    private String address;

    @SerializedName("contact")
    private String contact;

    @SerializedName("dilivery_place")
    private String dplace;

    @SerializedName("dilivery_place")
    private String fdetails;

    @SerializedName("no_of_normal")
    private int noOfNormal;

    @SerializedName("no_of_classified")
    private int noOfClassified;

    @SerializedName("no_of_cds")
    private int noOfCds;


    public UploadDataGetter(
            //constuctor's para
            int record_id,
            String full_name,
            String full_address,
            String contact_number,
            String dilivery_place,
            String further_details,
            int no_of_normal,
            int no_of_classified,
            int no_of_cds

    ) {
        id = record_id;
        name = full_name;
        address = full_address;
        contact = contact_number;
        dplace = dilivery_place;
        fdetails = further_details;

        noOfNormal = no_of_normal;
        noOfClassified = no_of_classified;
        noOfCds = no_of_cds;

        String img_collector;
        String dilivery_status;
        double geo_long;
        double geo_lat;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getDplace() {
        return dplace;
    }

    public void setDplace(String dplace) {
        this.dplace = dplace;
    }

    public String getFdetails() {
        return fdetails;
    }

    public void setFdetails(String fdetails) {
        this.fdetails = fdetails;
    }

    public int getNoOfNormal() {
        return noOfNormal;
    }

    public void setNoOfNormal(int noOfNormal) {
        this.noOfNormal = noOfNormal;
    }

    public int getNoOfClassified() {
        return noOfClassified;
    }

    public void setNoOfClassified(int noOfClassified) {
        this.noOfClassified = noOfClassified;
    }

    public int getNoOfCds() {
        return noOfCds;
    }

    public void setNoOfCds(int noOfCds) {
        this.noOfCds = noOfCds;
    }
}
```

now send this to new activity in intent like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
int.putExtra("data", YOUR_UPDATE_DATA_GETTER_OBJECT);
```

Now get the object in the new activity like this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class NewActivity extends Activity {


    private UploadDataGetter dataGetter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra("data")){
            dataGetter= (UploadDataGetter) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
            Log.d("NewActivity","ID: "+dataGetter.getId());
        }
    }
}
```